# R Shiny App Output not working when using dashboardPage() but owrks in fluidPage()

Tags: r, debugging, shiny, output, shinydashboard

I've been stuck for over a day trying to figure out why the output in my shiny app doesn't work whenever I try to build it as a dashboardPage() instead of as a fluidPage(). Oddly enough, when I use fluidPage() and arrange my outputs according to the sidebarLayout() method, it works perfectly fine - but it doesn't look as professional as the dashboard. All the data I'm using has been loaded into the R environment. Does anyone have any ideas as to why I cannot see my output? I've provided most of my code below, as well as a screenshot of the output for reference. Thank you

EDIT: Added some sample data to make this reproducible

Data

```
   #packages

   library(gtools) #for permute()
   library(shiny)
   library(shinydashboard) 
   
   #Data 

Serious.Offenses <- c("Assault","Battery", 
                  "Robbery", "Sex Offense", 
                  "Burglary", "Theft", 
                  "Homicide", "Criminal Sexual Assault",
                  "Motor Vehicle Theft","Kidnapping", 
                  "Arson", "Weapons Violation", "Narcotics")



crimesPerYear <- cbind(c(seq(2021,2008,-1)), c(108879,211121,260758,
                                           268423,268836,269592,
                                           264556,275634,307371,
                                           336182,351911,370430,
                                           392788,427126))  

 #Example of what's contained in big.List 

big.List <- lapply(1:14, 
                matrix, 
                data=as.integer(runif(1,6,20)), 
                nrow=77, 
                ncol=length(Serious.Offenses))

Socioeconomic.data <-  matrix(permute(rep((as.integer(runif(78,5,9))),13)), nrow = 78, ncol = 13)
Neighbourhoods <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:78,Socioeconomic.data))
```

Here's the sidebar

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("City-Wide Crime Statistics", tabName = "citywide", icon = icon("chart-area")),
  menuItem("Statistics By Neighbourhood", tabName = "nbh", icon = icon("vector-polygon")),
  menuItem("Measuring Crime Index", tabName = "fcc", icon = icon("chart-network"))
 )
)
```

Here's the body

```
body <- dashboardBody(

 tabItems(
   tabItem(tabName = "citywide",
        
        h4("Displaying the up-to-date crime data in city", 
           align = "left", 
           style = "color: black"),
        
        fluidRow(
          column(3, selectInput("which_year","Select a year: " ,choices = 2008:2021)),
          column(3, selectInput("which_crime", "Select a Criminal Offense:", choices = Serious.Offenses))
        ),
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title = "Crime analytics across the entire city",
            width = 5, 
            solidHeader = TRUE, 
            status = "primary",
            height = 500,
            textOutput("info1")
          ),
          box(
            title = "Socioeconomic data for the city",
            width = 5, 
            solidHeader = TRUE, 
            status = "primary",
            height = 500,
            textOutput("info2")
          )
        )
    ),

   tabItem(tabName = "nbh",
        
      #Similar code as above
   ),

  tabItem(tabName = "fcc",
        
     # Similar code as above
  )
)
```

And here is the server side of things as well as how I built the UI list.

```
  ui <- dashboardPage(
     skin = "purple",
     dashboardHeader(title = "Crime Analytics"),
     sidebar,
     body
   )
  server <- function(input, output) {
  output$info1 <-renderText ({

    mat <- big.List[[which(crimesPerYear[,1]==input$which_year)]]
    df <- as.data.frame(big.List[[which(crimesPerYear[,1]==as.numeric(input$which_year))]])
    rownames(df) <- Neighbourhoods[-78,1]
    count <- as.integer(big.List[[which(crimesPerYear[,1]==as.numeric(input$which_year))]] [,which(Serious.Offenses==as.character(input$which_crime))])
    match <- which(crimesPerYear[,1]==as.numeric(input$which_year))
    byType <- as.numeric(colSums(big.List[[match]]))


    paste("The total count of reported crimes throughout city for", input$which_year, "is a    staggering", sum(byType),"!",
        "\n",
        "\nThe Chicago Police department reported : ",
        "\n", byType[1], "counts of Assault",
        "\n", byType[2], "counts of Battery",
        "\n", byType[3], "counts of Robbery",
        "\n", byType[4], "counts of Sex Crimes",
        "\n", byType[5], "counts of Burglary",
        "\n", byType[6], "counts of Theft",
        "\n", byType[7], "counts of Homicide",
        "\n", byType[8], "counts of Sexual Assault",
        "\n", byType[9], "counts of Motor Vehicle Theft",
        "\n", byType[10], "counts of Kidnapping",
        "\n", byType[11], "counts of Arson",
        "\n", byType[12], "counts of Weapons Violation",
        "\n", byType[13], "counts of Narcotics Possesion",
        "\n", 
        "\nThe crime rate across the city was: ", round(100000*sum(byType)/Neighbourhoods[78,3], 1), "per 100,000", 
       "\nThe most common type of crime committed in City during", input$which_year, "was", colnames(df)[which.max(colSums(df))]
      )
   })
   ...
   ...
 }
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You are more likely to get a useful answer if you post a reproducible example.  Your example is not reproducible because you don't provide your data.  Also, your `renderText` mixes both data wrangling and data presentation.  This is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Try `body <- shinydashboard::dashboardBody(...)`.  Same for sidebar and header.  As @Limey stated, we cannot test your code without sample data, and a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't sure if it would have been an overload of information and I wrote this post quite late. I've added sample data and modified the code slightly so that my example is a reproducible one. Let me know if I should add anything else

Comment: @YBS I did try adding the  `shinydashboard::` portion but it did not change anything. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Please specify all the packages you are using.  Also, `permute()` is from which package?

Comment: @YBS `permute()` is from the gtools package, I added the libraries needed to run my code as given above. Otherwise I'm using ggplot2() and tmap() as well, for plot outputs

Comment: Your code runs fine for me.

Comment: @YBS runs fine as in, it also generates the appropriate output? I'm so curious as to why it won't work for me..

Comment: Yes, I get the appropriate output.  Perhaps you should restart your RStudio or even the laptop/PC/Mac.

Comment: I've done that twice now, i'll try doing it on my other PC to see if the issue persists. I updated some of my packages as well.. thanks for the help nonetheless